# How define variable in laravel component

Tags: php, variables, components, laravel-8

i use **laravel 8 components**, that according to doc can pass data and use it. but i need some modification passed data as variable that can be used in component

my code got *Undefined variable: covers* error

```
<x-item_h :item="$item"/>
```

item-h.blade.php

```
<div class="item-h">
    {{$item}}
    {{$covers}}
</div>
```

item-h.php

```
class Item_h extends Component
{
    public $item;
    public $covers;

    public function __construct($item )
    {
        $this->item = $item;

        if ($item->getCover->count() > 0) {
            $covers = $item->getCover;
        } else {
            $covers = $item->artists->getCover;
        }
        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.item_h');
    }
}
```

**so how define variable in component that can be use in it ?**

Thanks

Comment: you need to use `$this->covers` instead of `$covers` in your `Item_h` constructor.

Comment: @remul i test that before , not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add covers as when u are calling the component like this.

```
    <x-item_h :item="$item" covers/>
```

Now update the constructor and add give covers a default value of your choice, so that even u forget to give value to it, it will not crash your view

```
class Item_h extends Component
{
    public $item;
    public $covers;

    public function __construct($item ,$covers={{REPLACE WITH DEFAULT VALUE}})
    {
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->covers = $covers; 
        if ($item->getCover->count() > 0) {
            $covers = $item->getCover;
        } else {
            $covers = $item->artists->getCover;
        }
        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.item_h');
    }
}
```

I am sure this will fix your issue

Comment: Also if you want to send the covers as a variable you can do so, also you can change $covers to #this->covers; this will work perfectly